# In Unity, in what files is data about sprite sheet slicing stored?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, sprite, sprite-sheet

I have some sprite sheets in Unity that have been sliced up using the Sprite Editor in the IDE. However, I've been using git and when I pull the project the animations don't work - the slicing information has been lost. We've been git ignoring .meta files - could this be the problem? Where is sprite sheet slicing data stored?

[edit] Sprite sheet slicing data is stored in the .meta files for the sprite sheet image files. Does anyone know where data for the fields of scripts is stored? Copying the .meta files for scripts doesn't work - are these files getting replaced by Unity?

[edit2] It was the .meta files for the scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always add all the .meta files in the assets folder to the git. Otherwise you will run into lot of similar problems where things in the scenes, prefabs etc. are lost.

Comment: On the machine where data is missing, it is a good idea to close Unity and delete meta files with file browser before git pull. If Unity is on, it is generating new problematic meta files immediately after they have been deleted